How can I make outward-opening shutters easier to operate from within?
I would like to install aluminium shutters that open outwards, like this:

I see two potential issues:

When the shutter is open, and there are strong winds, they might shake the shutter, and it might hit the wall and make noise.
When the shutter is open, it is hard to pull it from within the room to close.

Two potential solutions are:

Put magnets on the wall and on the shutter, so that when the shutter is open, it is magnetized to the wall and not moved by winds;
Attach strings to the shutter, to allow pulling it from within the room.

These are two ad-hoc solutions; I believe there should be better ones, as I am not the first one installing shutters... what are more standard ways to make outward-opening shutters easier to use?

Do you mean a window stay?

A double window with a casement on the outside is a bad idea and even worse if, like the picture, the inner window is a tiny slider.  Don't do this!  Why do you want outward opening shutters?  In a very sunny climate (which I think you have) you want the shutters on the inside so you can adjust the louvers all through the day to let in just the right amount of light.  With double windows, if one is a casement, it's also more convenient if it opens inwards.    If YOUR shutters will be different to the ones in the picture, where it would make sense for them to open out, please describe.

Are they primarily storm shutters designed to protect the window from wind driven debris?

@jay613 I do not want the shutters to open inwards since this takes up space in the room. And the apartment is in a hilly region, which is quite cold and stormy in the winter.

@mikes yes, they are designed to protect the window during harsh weather, as well as provide privacy and darkness during sunny days.

In the homes in the USA, that had shutters in the 19th century there were devices that allowed the shutters to be opened and locked into place from inside the house.

Picture courtesy https://www.buildingmoxie.com/restoring-exterior-wood-shutters/
The shutters could be kept open, close to the house by using "Shutter dogs or tiebacks"

Shutter dog courtesy https://blog.diyshutters.com/
One or the other may work, there are items out there that should do what you need. That is, if it can be adapted to your windows.

In the 20th and 21st century, most US homes that have shutters have purely decorative ones, permanently mounted flush against the wall in the "open" position, and people have used drapes or shades when they want to block light.

OP's shutters are large and heavy.  Heavy framing, mechanically operated louvers and heavy metal hardware on the outer edge of the frame.  Both suggestions here are good, but, be careful adapting hardware meant for smaller, lighter, shutters.  Imagine high winds when the shutter is in any position.  Truly those shutters are poorly designed.

@keshlam , absolutely correct. Only on the high end homes I used to work on did the shutters actually work the way they should. But that is a very small percentage of the shutters that are used. Many are just for decoration. I would make an assumption that if the OP is going to go with shutters like the ones pictured, the supplier would also have its' own line of hardware like the one I have pictured, but made to fit their shutters. It would seem silly that they didn't.

@Jack: It wasn't clear to me at first glance whether they were installing new or adding stops to existing hinged shutters.

A Jack you're right.  Comment deleted, I'll make it a question to the Question instead.

@keshlam this is an interesting comment. Why are shutters rarely used nowadays? Apparently they have the advantage that they also protect the window from harsh whether, as well as make it harder for burglars to get in.

They aren't significantly useful at stopping burglars. And modern windows withstand most harsh weather quite well; the exceptions are things like hurricanes or tornadoes, where nothing short of plywood is going to protect the window. Basically, shutters went out of use as better windows, bug screens, curtains or draperies, and air conditioning came into use and addressed the needs better.

I would have to agree about the deterrent from burglars. With the aluminum shutters, that would make one heck of a noise trying to get through them, then through the window. Making noise is something burgulars are not trying to do.
